# Using python re regex in MongoDB $filter condition

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document like below:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    data: [ { zip: 001, city: "abc" }, { zip: 002, city: "xyz" } ]
}
```

I want to filter data array using python regex. But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
city = "abc"
regx = re.compile("^%s$" %city, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
for doc in db.testusers.aggregate([ { "$project": { "data": { "$filter": { "input": "$data", "as": "item", "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$item.city", regx ] } } } } } ]):
    json.dumps(doc)
```

It doesn't match anything.
Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

I think $filter does not support regex. See [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

I cannot test this here but it should work like according to this sample:

```
city_list = ["cityAbc", "Metroid"]
city_list = [re.compile("^" + str(c_id) + "$", re.IGNORECASE) for c_id in city_list]

pipe = [ { "$match" : {   "_id":{"$in" : city_list}}},
                { "$unwind" : "$rp"},
                {"$group":{"_id": "$_id", "rp": { "$push":  "$rp" }}} , {"$limit":500}] 

res = list(db.coll.aggregate(pipeline = pipe,allowDiskUse=True))
```